# Partial sort of std::list

Tags: c++, stl

I have a linked list that I want to sort part of, eg:

```
std::sort(someIterator, otherIterator, predicate);
```

std::sort requires random-access iterators so this approach doesn't work. There is a specialisation std::list::sort, but that can only sort the entire list. I don't think I have enough access to the list members to write something myself.

Is there a way to do this without changing to, say, vector?

Comment: and what is the main reason you're using list instead of vector? In spite of the fact std::vector have to perform move on avg. half elements (eg. when deleting), it is super fast thanks to cache. std::vector beats std::list even in frequent deleting and inserting on rand. pos. You have to have very large number of elements to profit by using list.

Comment: Well honestly I can't remember, since in the three and a half years since I asked I'm pretty sure it got refactored away somehow and I've long since left that job anyway. The point of the question was not so much about efficiency (although there's a fair chance that there was enough data that I wouldn't have wanted to duplicate it all on the fly) but more just curiosity; it seemed strange that I didn't seem to be able to do this partial sort and that there should be some way of achieving it.

Comment: oh :D my bad... I came across this question through search not through "active questions page" and did not realize that :) I actually thought this is active question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about unhooking the part of the list that you want sorted, into a standalone list,
then use the specialized list sort, then hook it back into the original list?

Comment: That's a good idea. It's easy to forget the power of the splice() method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you will have to use a [merge sort](http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_(C_Plus_Plus)).