# Use std::sort to find top N items in a std::vector

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I need to sort the elements in a `std::vector`, but I'm only interested in the top `N` items being sorted, not the entire list:

E.g. in a list of 10 elements, only first 3 have to be sorted. Don't care about the rest...

> **1,2,3**,6,7,4,9,8,5

Can this be done using `std::sort`?

**Edit**

I simply needed to find the top `N` items in a vector. `std::partial_sort_copy` was exactely what I needed.

Comment: This is a vague question - do you only want first three items to be sorted? Or to have three smallest elements of the whole list sorted at the beginning?

Comment: Maybe you'd want to take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217073/partial-sort-of-stdlist

Comment: If you got your question answered, **accept** the answer instead of editing the question to repeat the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) instead of `std::sort`. :)

Answer (score 8):

This is what [`std::partial_sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/) is for.

Comment: Your link says the initial part will be sorted: "the subrange [first,middle) contains the smallest elements of the entire range sorted in ascending order"

Comment: Thanks Lou.  I had `partial_sort` and `partition` confused in my head.

Answer (score 3):

If you require ordering then `partial_sort` will do it, otherwise if you only need to partition the range `nth_element` will do it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell the sort routine where you want to stop sorting:

```
std::vector<int> values;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    values.push_back(rand() % 10);

std::cout << "UNSORTED" << endl;
std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "SORTED (Partially)" << std::endl;
std::sort(values.begin(), values.begin() + 3);
std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Granted, the question as originally asked was very unclear, but it's now clear that the top 3 elements of the *entire* vector are needed, so your approach won't work.